# find the scalar equation of a plane with a given point and a parallel line

Tags: vectors

So the question was:

Find the scalar equation of a plane passing through the point $( 1, -5, 2)$ and parallel to the line $(x,y,z)= (2,0,3) + s(3,-1,-2)$.  Grade $12$ level explanation please.

I completed the question assuming the position vector (2,0,3) was ON the plane, BUT, I do not think it is necessarily correct that it is ON the plane. I do understand that the direction vector is (3,-1,-2). I also understand that [x,y'z]= (1,-5,2) + s[ 3,-1,-2) IS  a line on the plane. I also understand that I need to find a second line with which to cross to get the normal vector, and the information I need to complete the scalar equation.

I wanted to confirm that it is possible for the given line to be parallel and not lie ON the plane. I also would like to understand how to find a second line on the plane. Someone suggested choosing an arbitrary non- parallel line, but how can I be sure an arbitrary line is ON this plane? The only way I can think to do that is to choose one of the zeros? ie. (0,0,-2).

I do not understand all the fuss about this question. I am  just trying to re-familiarize myself with grade 12 vectors and get an understanding of this question which seemed to be either missing information, or I was missing something.

Comment: You could do your homework yourself or at least try it! What is your question? Where did you stuck? What are your efforts?

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: I have modified my question and no one has responded. I thoughtifollowed

Answer (score 0):

The plan should obviously pass through $(1,-5,2)$, but also through $(2,0,3)$ (for $s=0$) and through $(5,-1,1)$ ($s=1$), I think you should be able to find such a plane.

Answer (score 0):

A scalar equation of a plane is $Ax + By + Cz + D = 0$, where $[A, B, C]$ is the direction vector of the normal to the plane.

If you use the direction vector of the line as one of the direction vectors of the plane, and pick another arbitrary non-parallel direction vector, you now have the vector equation of the plane, which by definition is parallel to the line.

You should be able to find the normal of the plane by using the cross product of the two direction vectors, and substituting your point into the scalar equation to solve for $D$.

This seems like a homework question, so I'll let you do the calculations. :)

EDIT: The arbitrary non-parallel vector must be of the form $[x, y, x] = [-1, 5, 2] + t[x, y, z]$. This ensures that it is on the plane! As long as this is not parallel to the other direction vector $[x, y, z] = [-1, 5, 2] + s[3, -1, -2]$, you should be able to find your normal vector to the plane by crossing these two vectors.

The reason why an arbitrary non-parallel vector can be chosen is kind of hard to explain, so I'll try to use an image. Hold a pen above your desk, and pick a point on your desk. How many planes pass through the point without intersecting the pen? Infinitely many, all of which seem to "rotate" around an axis which is parallel to your pen. Therefore, you can pick any arbitrary non-parallel vector with its tail at the point to create your plane.

Comment: I have improved (edited) my question as requested and no one has responded. I am new to this site and it is discouraging to receive such negative feedback when I am just trying to become familiar with it.

Comment: That's alright, I'll try to clarify my answer.

Comment: Oh! So there are infinitely many possible correct answers -  I am creating the plane,  not being asked to identify a specific plane! Oh my gee!! I have been puzzling over this for weeks!

Comment: @Gems: Haha, glad to help. I don't understand why this question got so much negative feedback; it was a good question even if somewhat ambiguous.